# OpenAI Gym: nested spaces to/from dataclasses?

Tags: python, openai-gym, python-dataclasses

Consider this example nested observation space found in the [source code](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/spaces/dict.py) of the OpenAI Gym `spaces.Dict` class:

```
self.nested_observation_space = spaces.Dict({
    'sensors':  spaces.Dict({
        'position': spaces.Box(low=-100, high=100, shape=(3,)),
        'velocity': spaces.Box(low=-1, high=1, shape=(3,)),
        'front_cam': spaces.Tuple((
            spaces.Box(low=0, high=1, shape=(10, 10, 3)),
            spaces.Box(low=0, high=1, shape=(10, 10, 3))
        )),
        'rear_cam': spaces.Box(low=0, high=1, shape=(10, 10, 3)),
    }),
    'ext_controller': spaces.MultiDiscrete((5, 2, 2)),
    'inner_state':spaces.Dict({
        'charge': spaces.Discrete(100),
        'system_checks': spaces.MultiBinary(10),
        'job_status': spaces.Dict({
            'task': spaces.Discrete(5),
            'progress': spaces.Box(low=0, high=100, shape=()),
        })
    })
})
```

In order to construct observations from this space, one would need to make a `dict` that contains all these properties, which is annoying. It would be nicer if one could work with dataclasses instead. This could be done manually, i.e. one could define a series of dataclasses with the same properties as the dict:

```
@dataclass
class Sensors:
    position: np.ndarray
    velocity: np.ndarray
    front_cam: typing.Tuple(np.ndarray, ...)
    rear_cam: np.ndarray

@dataclass 
class JobStatus:
    task: int
    progress: np.ndarray

@dataclass
class InnerState:
    charge: int
    system_checks: np.ndarray
    job_status: JobStatus

@dataclass 
class NestedObservation:
    sensors: Sensors
    ext_controller: np.ndarray
    inner_state: InnerState
```

then to construct an observation, one would create an instance of `NestedObservation` and then call `asdict` on it. I.e.

```
obs_object = NestedObservation(...)
obs = asdict(obs)
assert(self.nested_observation_space.contains(obs))
```

The issue with manually defining these dataclasses is that if one wants to modify the structure of the space, they will need to modify both the `Space` object and the dataclasses, which can introduce bugs, if not done carefully.

Is there any way to define the space structure in one place, and then have access to both a `Space` object and dataclasses automatically? I'm just finding it hard to write good code with complex spaces like this one.